# Save markups to database on close event

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am attempting to insert markups data into a cloud database by utilizing `Autodesk.Viewing.TOOL_CHANGE_EVENT`. However, it appears that this event is triggered before the markups data is extracted via `markupsExtension.generateData()

```js
//Make sure the extentions loaded
 viewer?.current?.loadModel(path.urlPath, {}, function onSuccess() {
 viewer?.current?.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore");
viewer?.current?.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui");
}); 

 React.useEffect(() => {
    viewer?.current?.addEventListener(
      Autodesk.Viewing.TOOL_CHANGE_EVENT,
      (x) => {
        if (x.active && x.toolName === "markups.core") {
          getAllMarkupsFromDatabase(viewer.current);
        } else if (!x.active && x.toolName === "markups.core") {
        //here the event close before getting the data
          saveMarkupsToDatabase(viewer.current);
        }
      }
    );
  }, [isGeometryLoaded]);
  
//Save the markups data.
async function saveMarkupsToDatabase(viewer: any) {
  const markupsExtension = await viewer.loadExtension(
    "Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore"
  );

  const markupsData = await markupsExtension.generateData();
  console.log({ markupsData });

  //Save to database

   localStorage.setItem("markups", markupsStringData);
 

}
```

I am uncertain if there is a way to obtain the data prior to closing the markups extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

```js
//I used:
  viewer?.current?.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore").then((ext) =>
    //@ts-ignore
    ext.addEventListener(
      //@ts-ignore
      Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EVENT_EDITMODE_LEAVE,
      console.log
    )
  );
  
//insted of:
viewer?.current?.addEventListener(
      Autodesk.Viewing.TOOL_CHANGE_EVENT,
      async (x) => {
        const extension = await viewer?.current?.loadExtension(
          "Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore"
        ))
       if (!x.active && x.toolName === "markups.core" && markupsData?.id) {})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Adam and I solved this with you, during the Copenhagen Accelerator, right ?
​
Let me know if it's all solved.
​

Comment: Hello Michael,

We worked on the extension of measurement. I have been attempting to use toolbar events to extract markup data and store it in the database. However, I encountered a problem where the event was firing before extracting the markups SVG string.

Fortunately, I was able to solve the issue by implementing a button. Now, I click the button before closing the markups  to get the markups data.